# Delete a list of entity with RequestFactory (GWT)

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, gwt-2.2

How can I delete a list of entity with RequestFactory?

```
InstanceRequest<List<XProxy>, Void> remove();
```

Of course, this is not working, because the first parameter has to be like this: P extends BaseProxy; but is there a similar way?

---

I want to delete the selected entities of my CellTable from the database. And I am using MultiSelectionModel, and CheckboxCell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `InstanceRequest` means that the method is an instance method on the domain method for the first type argument (similar to looking for a `remove()` on a `List` in what you tried).

You have to use a `Request` and pass the `List` as an argument to the method. The presence of a `@ServiceLocator` on the `RequestContext` will tell RequestFactory whether to look for a static or an instance method.

```java
Request<Void> remove(List<XProxy> list);
```